# Callback function as an argument in Java

Tags: java, function, callback, arguments

I am new to Java programming and have got a question. I saw in JavaScript that you can give a function as an argument to a function. How does this work with Java?

I want to accomplish the following: Say I have a function A which goes through a list. For every list item, function A `System.out.println` just the text or it parses the text with function B and `System.out.println` this value. My use case is a little bit different, but most important all functions return void and just call a function or do a database query, so there are no actual return values.

Thanks in advance for your time.

*Is it correct to call this a callback function?*

Comment: this might help you: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces

Comment: I suggest reading a tutorial on lambda expressions, e.g. [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: Define a callback interface, pass an instance of a class that implements that interface to your function. Invoke it at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
List<String> yourList = new ArrayList<String>();

yourList.add("item1");
yourList.add("item2");
yourList.add("item3");
yourList.add("item4");

functionA(yourList);
```

---

```
public void functionA(List<String> yourList){
    for (String item: yourList) {
            functionB(item);
        }
}

public void functionB(String item){
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

> ```
> Or
> ```

```
public void functionA(List<String> yourList){
    yourList.forEach((item) -> {
                System.out.println(item);
            });
}
```

> ```
> Or
> ```

```
public void functionA(List<String> yourList){
    for (String item: yourList) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
}
```

Comment: Exactly, but to make it less monolithic, I want to hand over functionB to functionA, so functionA goes (not only but also) through each element with a lambada expression and applies functionB, or functionC, etc. on each element.